# Ruby - Delete a value from array

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-5

When I try to delete a value from array and map with same array object to create new array but its not working getting error undefined method 'delete'.

```
@test = ["ab","cd","ef"]
@test.map.delete("ab")
```

NoMethodError (undefined method `delete' for #)

Comment: You can't chain delete after map. Can't you explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: i want to delete a value from array and map to same array object as new array so that i can use in different method

Comment: How about `test - [‘ab’]`?

Comment: still its not working

Comment: @AnsonG Did you tried using `delete_if`? It deletes every element of `self` for which block evaluates to true. Array gets changed instantly every time the block is called.

Comment: Can you please explain what issue you are facing?

Answer (score 3):

You can also try this using [tap](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap),

```
irb(main):009:0> test = ["ab","cd","ef"]
=> ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
irb(main):010:0> test.tap {|i| i.delete("ab")}
=> ["cd", "ef"]
```

Or

```
irb(main):019:0> test = ["ab","cd","ef"]
=> ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
irb(main):020:0> test -= ["ab"]
=> ["cd", "ef"]
```

Or you can use [delete_if](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/delete_if)

```
irb(main):031:0> @test = ["ab","cd","ef"]
=> ["ab", "cd", "ef"]
irb(main):032:0> @test.delete_if{|i|i=="ab"}
=> ["cd", "ef"]
irb(main):033:0> @test
=> ["cd", "ef"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you meant to use something like [reject](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)?

You could do the following if you want to delete an item from the array with a matching string:

```
test = ["ab","cd","ef"]; test.reject{|a| a == "ab"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@test` is array object and `@test.map` will return enumerator object. `delete` is Array method & not a Enumerator method.

You can directly call `delete` on `@test`

```
@test.delete('ab')
```

Comment: but when i navigate to different method and access @test, I am getting all values including deleted value ('ab').

Comment: I tried out ray's solution and it works for me. Is the @test variable being updated somewhere else? https://repl.it/repls/WindyNaiveOrder

Comment: yup its been updated in other method as well, anyways thanks now fixed the issue its working